# Linux - find - How to exclude a directory

Tags: linux, find

Inside the /tmp I want to find files older than 180 day, but I also want to exclude some folders from the search like ./vboxdrv-Module.symvers.
How can I perform the task with find?

Answer (score 3):

This syntax will do what you want:

```
find -not -newermt 2016-11-10 -not -path "./vboxdrv-Module.symvers/*"
```

Change with whatever settings you want.

Add as many `-not -path` you want after each other. Ie.

```
find -not -newermt 2016-11-10 -not -path "./folder1/*" -not -path "./folder2/*"
```

Or if you want to do it from another folder:

```
find /tmp/ -not -newermt 2016-11-10 -not -path "/tmp/folder1/*" -not -path "/tmp/folder2/*"
```

Comment: Good answer, but your examples should show what the questioner wants, eg `-not -newermt 2016-11-10`, instead of your `-name` clause.

Comment: You're right. I was being too lazy. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Is the a POSIX variant? I need it cause I've got to perform the same action on AIX

Comment: I'm unsure about the time in POSIX, but it sounds like you have that. If that's the case just exchange -not with !. Ie. ! -path "/tmp/folder1/*"